# How to keep jeans crisp

Tags: clothing, personal-care

I wear jeans to office and is in jeans at home too so mostly in jeans but my office jeans become too flat and dull. Some people have jeans which are dark in colours and crisp. It is like they custome tailored made them.

I know there is a saying that do not wash you jeans but I feel I have to after a week coz of stains and might smell.

How can I achieve crispy and as new as brand look for my jeans. I wear Levi jeans

Answer (score 2):

Don't dry them in the dryer, the rubbing is where almost all the wear comes from over time. Instead, air dry them. I put an air circulating fan pointed at my clothes and they dry fast, like being outside in a breeze.

Also, I suggest turning them inside out when washing, just for a little extra protection against wear when cleaning

Comment: Hi Ack, Welcome to Lifehacks.

Answer (score 1):

Stay Cool…

Treat your blue denim as you would delicate fabrics when laundering to preserve the deep (blue/black/red/?) colour and crisp feel.
Here are a few points to keep in mind:

- Choose the "delicate" setting on the washer if there is one.
- Avoid hot water and strong detergent which works to thin the cotton fibres.
- Avoid hot air temperatures when drying which flex and break (shortening) the fibres and softens them.
- Avoid fabric softeners which work counter to your effort for keeping the "body" in your jeans.

One more thing™… It's not unheard of to have your jeans tailored. You're unique.

Good luck.

Comment: Can I make the already jeans crisp

Comment: @Nofel I don't know. If nothing else, you can try to conserve what you have.

Comment: In addition to your suggestions, you should turn your jeans inside out before washing and turn them back right side after drying. That way if anything rubs against the denim during the washing, it doesn't rub off the outer crisp layer of dye.